# Root etiology of non-pituitary low T4 and low TSH

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, human-anatomy, endocrinology

**Please note:** I'd like to preface this question by stating that this is neither homework nor me seeking medical advice. I am simply trying to understand the biological, physiological root etiology behind various thyroid-related structures.

This question shows research and is not a duplicate.

---

My *undertanding* of the pituitary gland is that it will produce TSH when it senses **total T4** (not free T4) is low. So if both total T4 and TSH are low, this implies two things:

- There is some underlying reason why T4 is low; but moreover...
- There is some other (or related) reason as to why TSH is low

In all the literature I can find, the main antagonist in this scenario is a malfunctioning pituitary gland.

So I ask: if the pituitary gland is deemed functional and non-diseased, are there any other root causes for **both** a low total T4 and a low TSH? Biologicaly/physiologically, how do they work to produce this low level of hormone production?

Comment: Are you sure such a condition exists? Can you link to it? Also, are you sure about your [total T4 statement](http://www.thyroidmanager.org/chapter/physiology-of-the-hypothalmic-pituitary-thyroidal-system/)?

Comment: Thanks @anongoodnurse (+1) - [here](https://labtestsonline.org/understanding/analytes/t4/tab/test/) is an article showing that a low TSH and a low/normal T4 are attributed to pituitary disorder. I can provide other links as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it can happen with a pituitary condition, but you stipulated in your scenario that the pituitary was healthy. I'm asking you if you know that condition to exist, and can you link to it?

Comment: Thanks again for verifying @anongoodnurse (+1) - if you scroll to the bottom of that link, you'll see a table where it shows that low TSH and low T4 can be caused by **two** categories of conditions: (1) "*rare pituitary (secondary) hypothyroidism*" (which like you understand, we're assuming to not be the case here as the pituitary *is* healthy), and **(2) "*Non-thyroidal illness*"**.

Comment: When you ask a question, it's much easier to summarize the part you have a question about rather than make a user read the whole paper just to understand what you question.  That's why I asked for more information in my first comment.